# How do I escape special characters in oh-my-zsh alias?

Tags: linux, zsh, alias, oh-my-zsh

So I am trying to create an alias that would list files in current directory like "ls -lAh" would, but only with specific columns that I want. So I've come up with this command:

```sh
ls -lAh | awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "; OFS=" "} {print $6,$7,$8,$5,$9}'
```

This would only print columns that I need, which are date and time, file size and file name in that order.

However if I want to create an alias for this command, I obviously need to escape a lot of characters so they get interpreted properly, but I am failing to do so. Sometimes when I put a backslash in front of a single quote or a dollar sign, it just breaks one way or the other and I can't make it work.

Please help me understand how I'm supposed to escape the special characters so this gets interpreted correctly.

In case it changes anything, I'm on MacOS. Please do ask for clarifications if needed.

Edit:- Here is what I tried when attempting to actually create an alias:

```sh
alias lah='ls -lAh | awk \'BEGIN\{FS=" "; OFS=" "\} \{print \$6,\$7,\$8,\$5,\$9}\''
```

I tried putting backslashes before every special character, on my first try I just put them before the single quotes, that didn't work and it was telling me something like `zsh: parse error at {`. Then I put a backslash before each curly brace, and that didn't work, apparently dollar signs are also special characters, so I put backslashes before those, but then whenever I press return after typing the command, it makes a new line that says `quote>`, where I had to put a single quote to end the command, and when I do that it prints this: `zsh: command not found: \{print`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show your attempt(s) to define an alias. Then it will be easier to help.

Comment: @AlekseiK : Don't backslash the curly braces.  You are between single apostrophs, so you have to escape only the single quotes. BTW, I think you would get much less headache if you would define a function instead of an alias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is how to correctly quote with single quotes a string that already contains single quotes.

```
ls -lAh | awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "; OFS=" "} {print $6,$7,$8,$5,$9}'
```

To get a correctly quoted string easily you could use ZSH's key sequence <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> (single quote).

- Type the string you want to quote, e.g.
  `ls -lAh | awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "; OFS=" "} {print $6,$7,$8,$5,$9}'`
- Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> followed by <kbd>'</kbd> (single quote). In your example this should give you something like
  `'ls -lAh | awk '\''BEGIN{FS=" "; OFS=" "} {print $6,$7,$8,$5,$9}'\'`
- Continue with the rest of your command or copy&paste the quoted string into your editor.

In general, to quote a single quote inside single quotes you need to insert a closing quote `'`, an escaped quote `\'` and if necessary an opening quote `'` like this:

```
alias lah='ls -lAh | awk '\''BEGIN{FS=" "; OFS=" "} {print $6,$7,$8,$5,$9}'\'
```

Comment: Thanks, someone previously answered similarly but their answer got deleted for whatever reason, though your explanation is clearer, now I at least understand how this works

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an alias, you should set up a function in your `.bashrc`.
For example:

```
ldir() {
ls -lAh | awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "; OFS=" "} {print $6,$7,$8,$5,$9}'}
```

Then reload the bashrc:

```
source .bashrc
```

You should now be able able to run the `ldir` command.

Comment: I know I could make a function for this but I kinda just wanted everything to be an alias just so it's simpler to manage, also I'm not using bash, I'm using zsh, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use double-quotes for the 'outside' quotes, since escapes are supported in double-quoted strings. The trick is knowing what needs to be escaped:

```
alias lah="ls -lAh | awk 'BEGIN{FS=\" \"; OFS=\" \"} {print \$6,\$7,\$8,\$5,\$9}'"
```

Note that if you ask `zsh` to display this alias, it'll normalize it to use single quotes, as in @Bodo's answer:

```
% alias lah
lah='ls -lAh | awk '\''BEGIN{FS=" "; OFS=" "} {print $6,$7,$8,$5,$9}'\'
```